# Tag for Demo/In-Development sites

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have a question about my Webmasters Stack Exchange post: [Ways to show a demo site to a client without a server](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114755/ways-to-show-a-demo-site-to-a-client-without-a-server)

Just wondering whether the community thinks a tag for [demo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demo) and/or [in-development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-development) sites would be useful. Specifically I just asked a question regarding a demo site for a client and there aren't really any tags relating to any of that. A [demo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demo) Tag would help distinguish that it's not regarding a live on the web site, and that it's for demonstration purposes, so some elements would be more flexible than a "real" or "normal" site, and that it might not be finished.

There is also a [development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) tag I noticed, however it's not very clear from just the name what exactly (Q's RE: the development process, Q's RE: sites in development etc.) that refers to and it has no usage-guidance so I was unwilling to attach that to my question.

Comment: I'd also like to note I'm more than mildly annoyed about having to wait nearly an hour before being allowed to post this.

Comment: As you gain reputation here, you won't have so many limits on your account.   I'm not sure exactly why you had to wait an hour, but it may be the "new user restrictions" that are removed at only 10 reputation: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges   I see that you have some reputation on other StackExchange sites as well.  One you reach 200 reputation somewhere, you will get 100 reputation on any new sites you join.  It is called the [site association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) and it will be helpful in avoiding limits.

Comment: Once you reach 300 reputation, you can also create tags yourself.   In the meantime asking here if they can be created is fine.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yeah, I know about the association bonus, I'm just sorta spread thin across a bunch of sites so no one site is high enough to grant it to the others. I've seen it mentioned that I can just make my own tags eventually, I just would think it best to confer rather than being a lone wolf and having the tag I create never be used again.

Comment: Tags that are used on a single question are automatically removed after 6 months ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki)), so that isn't a huge danger.   If you create a tag you can also go through old questions and edit the best most relevant ones to add the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Although tags already exist for [development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) and [web-development](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development), these would seem to be more concerned with the *development process* than conducting *demonstrations* for others, as you noted.

I think there could be questions asking about strategies and techniques on how to demonstrate to others: website designs & layouts, modifications & improvements, performance & tracking, ads & marketing, beta testing, etc..., which would seem to fall under the [responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmaster) of a webmaster.

I therefore created a [demonstration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demonstration) tag and added it to your question. For its description, I added:

> Anything related to the demonstration of a website, including: website
>   designs & layouts, modifications & improvements, performance & tracking,
>   ads & marketing, beta testing, etc...

I've also created a [demo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demo) tag and added it as a synonym to the `demonstration` tag, so that if a user types `demo` they'll be provided with the `demonstration` tag. The reason I didn't chose`demo` as the main tag is because it's often used in reference to *software demos*, as the [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demo) tag on Stack Overflow indicates.

Comment: Could you provide tips on making the question more about strategies & techniques? That was my intention. Looking at the options I listed having looked into, screenshots and MHTML files are both strategies (Screenshots are rather obvious and I haven't asked for software to generate an mhtml file), and though HTTrack itself is software, I was more referring to (intending to atleast) what it produces being useful, and there are other ways of generating that.

Comment: I edited your question on the main site so that it's focused more on strategies and techniques versus recommendations for tools and software, and reopened it. (The discussion here should really be limited to just tags)